# Shouldn't the 'rights' tag be a synonym of 'permissions'?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tag [permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/permissions) is used for all questions relating to system permissions, whether it's filesystem permissions, permissions to burn DVDs, etc.

We also have the [rights](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rights) tag which contains questions that would be part of [permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/permissions) anyways.

Can we make [rights](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rights) a synonym of [permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/permissions)>

Comment: Thanks @Oli for approving the synonym.